# Jquery find all elements with custom attribute begin with, get rest of it's name and it's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say we have element with custom attribute

```
... bind-html="varName" ...
```

I want to find all elements with attribute beginning with `"bind-"`,

then get second part of it's name, which is unknown, in this case `"html"`.

And at last get it's value `"varName"`.

How do i achieved this with Jquery? I don't want to use second attribute to describe attibute to bind (like `..  bind="varName" attr="html"  ..`)

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do it this way? It doesn't seem good practice to me.

Comment: well its not a good practice but this will give you control of attributes if you are debugging a page in console dev tool plus one up vote for a fantastic question

Comment: couldn't understand *I don't want to use second attribute to describe attibute to bind*, could you pleas explain the required output? and does the custom attribute always start with `bind`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop through each object's attributes `this.attributes` and use the attribute's `name` and `value` properties.

Running example:

```js
$("input").each(function() {
    $.each(this.attributes, function() {
        if (this.name.indexOf('bind-') == 0) {
            console.log(this.name + ' has the value: ' + this.value);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input bind-koby='hello'>
<input bind-douek='stack'>
<input will-not-show='yes'>
<input bind-hello='overflow'>
```

Comment: I answered 20 minutes before u did

Comment: so your answer is like mine

Comment: sorry for misconception i guess you edited your answer before me, i saw your edited answer after i answered

Comment: @hsnbl no problem buddy, everything is OK.

Answer (score 1):

well that what you are looking for like

```
<div bind-html="varName">hi there i am </div>
```

well hi thats me

```
var namer = $(" *[attr*='bind']").text();
console.log(namer);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="bindable" data-bind="html:varName1"></div>
<div class="bindable" data-bind="css:varName2"></div>
<div class="bindable" data-bind="js:varName3"></div>
<div class="bindable" data-bind="whatEver:varName4"></div>

(function(){
  let bindables = $('.bindable');
  bindables.each(function(){
  let bindData = $(this).data('bind');
  let bindDataArray = bindData.split(":");
  console.log(bindDataArray);
 });
}());
```

**now u will get array with data u want**

Comment: after u get bindDataArray u will have an array of both value u want

Comment: I like your solution and will use it. But class selector is not needed. Only find('[data-bind]'). Sorry, i accepted another answer because it answer my question literally.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all elements and their attributes which contain `bind-` by using jquery `.properties` and `.indexOf()` like following example.

```js
// $("*") selects all elements in your html
$("*").each(function() {
  $.each(this.attributes, function() {
    // checks whether element has an attribute starts with "bind-" or not
    if(this.specified && this.name.indexOf("bind-") !== -1) {
        console.log("Attr Name: "+ this.name + " Attr Value: " + this.value)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span bindNot-html="bindNot">element1</span>
<div bind-html="varName1">element2</div>
<a bind-html2="varName2">element3</a>
<div bind-html3="varName3">element4</div>
<span bindNot-html="bindNot">element5</span>
```

Comment: Based on my question your answer is best. But i thing i will use andrew saeed approach.

Comment: @YBorys Unconciously I have used method which is almost same with Koby Douek's answer so He answered before me.Therefore I think his answer deserves to be accepted answer more than mine. Please consider this.